# Excel (2003) - Automatic insert date on a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I don't really know if this is a programming question, but I am sure one of you can easily help me with this one.

I am trying to create a automatic "inserted date" function inside excel. i.e. When a person inputs data in a row in my excel document I want another cell to automatically show the date of insertion.

Standing inside the cell i am trying to show the date, I've written the following:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C20);1;TODAY())
```

This works great, until I open it the day after. Clearly it will set the date to "TODAY", but if I want it to only update once, at the time of the insertion - how would I do that?

Thinking something like this (Java - pseudo).

```
IF(!OTHER.CELL.ISBLANK() && THIS.CELL.ISBLANK()){
   THIS.CELL = TODAY();
}
```

Now, how to do that in Excel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use the `Worksheet_Change` Event

1. Right click your sheet tab
2. View - Code
3. Copy and Paste in the code below

This code

- tracks and change made to column C of the Activesheet
- puts in the current data and user logon name to each corresponding cell in column D

Only changed column C cells are captured as specified in this line
`Set rng1 = Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target)`

The `Application.EnableEvents = False` is used to stop the code refiring when column D is writing to

You could easily adapt this to
1) write to a different (perhaps hidden) log sheet
2) write to a text file instead

Pls let me know if you want any updates

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now() & " - " & Environ("username")
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I must applaud the thorough answer, with screens from excel. :)